# Asp.net MVC pass Date to setDate Datepicker on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, datepicker

I am using MVC 5, i have a date-picker but it doesn't show date in the input when page is first time loaded. 
I am trying to add date from model class property to date-picker on page load:

```js
 <script type="text/javascript">
        // here to set the Model.MaximumDaysAheadBookable in the datepicker maxDate property
        var maxdate = @Model.MaximumDaysAheadBookable;

        $(document).ready(function () {
            var Arrival = @Model.Parameters.Checkin.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy");
            var Departure = @Model.Parameters.Checkout.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy");
            $("#Arrival").datepicker({
                setDate: Arrival,
                minDate: 0,
                maxDate: maxdate,
                dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
                showOn: "button",
                buttonImage: "img/ui_cal_icon.gif",
                buttonImageOnly: true,
                buttonText: "Select date",

            });

            $("#Departure").datepicker({
                setDate: Departure,
                minDate: 0,
                maxDate: maxdate + 1,
                dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
                showOn: "button",
                buttonImage: "img/ui_cal_icon.gif",
                buttonImageOnly: true,
                buttonText: "Select date",
            });

        });
    </script>
```

This is the model class property :

```
  public class SessionParameters
   {
    public DateTime Checkin { get; set; } = DateTime.Today.Date;
    public DateTime Checkout { get; set; } =     DateTime.Today.Date.AddDays(1);
   }
```

this is .cshtml :

```html
 <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-2">
                            <p class="font">@Resource.criteria_Arrival</p>
                            <input class="calendarr font" name="Arrival" readonly type="text" id="Arrival" onchange="changedDate()">

                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-2">
                            <p class="font">@Resource.criteria_Departure</p>
                            <input class="calendarr font" name="Departure" readonly type="text" id="Departure">
                        </div>
```

Comment: This is why MVC is dead to me.

Comment: Pls add your cshtml too to the question

Comment: Why are you not just binding it to your form controls using `@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Checkin)`? here is no reason to do this in the script

Comment: @User3250 i update the question with .cshtml

Comment: @StephenMuecke i do it like this because i have more than java-script function fired in this control  to call java-script function

Comment: Try using `startDate` instead of `setDate`

Comment: That has nothing to do with it. Just use `@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Checkin, "MM/dd/yyyy")` and the value will be set when the view is loaded.

Comment: @StephenMuecke When i write this line : ` @Html.TextBoxFor(Model => Model.Parameters.Checkin, "MM/dd/yyyy")`   it gives me MM/dd/yyyy  in the textbox

Comment: Oops, that should be `@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Parameters.Checkin, "{0:MM/dd/yyyy"})`

Comment: @StephenMuecke yes this is right now i get the date